# Recognizing the last button that was clicked C#

Tags: c#, .net, button, textbox, focus

I have 3 buttons btn1 btn2 btn3 and a textbox 
when i click any button it will focus on the textbox, my problem is that when I will press the escape I want to focus on the last button that was clicked. For example i clicked btn2 when i pressed esc it will focus back on btn2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here all three buttons are linked with the common click event "btn_Click".

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string controlName = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        controlName = btn.Name;
        txtBox.Focus();
    }

    private void txtBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Controls[controlName].Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx men it helps a lot

Comment: You should choose an answer, when you solve your problem.